# does bugzilla have an updated dump for all of its project

Tags: data-request

I am planning on text mining bug reports. so i am in need of a dataset of bug report.
does Bugzilla have an updated dump for all of its project?
does any other bug tracking system provide free access to their archives?

Comment: This sounds like a question specific to Bugzilla and would most likely depend on the version of Bugzilla the project(s) you are interested in is (are) using.

Comment: If you're asking about functionality of software, you should consult the documentation of the software.  If you're asking if there's a repository of dumps from all bugzilla projects ... I sure hope not, as that would expose flaws that might not be ready for public release.  (and if there was one, the Bugzilla website would be the place to start).  I'm leaning towards closing this, as it smacks of a 'homework' type question (in that you haven't even tried to solve the problem yourself).

Comment: @joe you are sure that ticketing systems "dont provide open datasets". Then how come this question fall under "homework help".

Comment: @Skram i am interested in ecllise and mozilla